# CI/CD recommendation

Tags: .net, version-control, automated-tests, containers, cicd

I would like to ask for your opinion about "best" (stable, modern, complex, supported) CI/CD solution for .NET oriented SW company.

Current oldschool state: small SW company up to 10 developers, SVN + CruiseControl.Net + Wix for generation msi installation packages.

We would like switch to some modern technologies (automation of building, testing, containerizing, deployment, etc.) with remaining Wix tasks. We don't want to publish our source codes into public repositories like GitHub etc.

Many thank for your ideas!

Comment: Best is what is working for you. Have you ever considered to improve the current system before replacing it (apart from Wix)? And the list of the modern technologies does not contain _version control software_, is that by intention?